# Keeping track of points in simple console game

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around this. Every time the player makes a wrong guess, it should subtract his/her *bet* from the *initial balance*.
Since it is in a loop, it always takes the initial balance from the beginning spits out the same balance every time. (obviously)
I've tried assigning different variables and just can't seem to figure it out.

I've omitted the medium and hard difficulty methods as they are of no use right now, until I figure out this one.

My Main() only calls the setDifficulty(). Nothing else.

```
class Control
{
    int selectedNumber = 0;
    Random num = new Random();
    bool playAgain = true;
    int difficulty = 0;
    int bet = 0;
    int initialBalance = 20;
    int runningCredits = 0;
    int credits = 0;

    public Control()
    { }

    //sets game difficulty
    public void SetDifficulty() 
    {


        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Please select level of difficulty between 1 - 100");
        difficulty = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (difficulty >= 1 && difficulty <= 20)
            LetsPlayEasy();


        else if (difficulty >= 21 && difficulty <= 50)
            LetsPlayMedium();


        else if (difficulty >= 51 && difficulty <= 100)
            LetsPlayHard();


        else
        {
            SetDifficulty();
        }


    }

    //easy level method
    public void LetsPlayEasy()
    {
        //variables
        int userGuess;
        int numGuesses = 0;
        selectedNumber = num.Next(1, 101);

        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        Console.WriteLine("Difficulty level = EASY");

        Console.WriteLine("\nBeggining credit balance = " + initialBalance);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease place a bet. You will lose those credits for every incorrect guess!");
        bet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nGuess a number between 1 and 100.");
            userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            numGuesses++;

            UI output = new UI();
            output.CompareNumbers(userGuess, ref selectedNumber, ref playAgain, ref numGuesses);


            runningCredits = (initialBalance - bet);
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou have " + runningCredits + " credits remaining.");

        } while (playAgain == true);
    }
```

---

```
class UI
{
    Random num = new Random();
    int keepGoing;

    public UI()
    { }

    //compare user's guess to selected number
    public void CompareNumbers(int userGuess, ref int selectedNumber, ref bool playAgain, ref int numGuesses)
    {
        Control difficulty = new Control();
        Admin say = new Admin();


        if (userGuess > selectedNumber)
        {
            Console.Beep(600, 300);
            Console.WriteLine("\nToo High! Guess Again!");

        }

        else if (userGuess < selectedNumber)
        {
            Console.Beep(300, 300);
            Console.WriteLine("\nToo Low! Guess Again!");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.Beep(350, 300);
            Console.Beep(380, 200);
            Console.Beep(380, 100);
            Console.Beep(500, 1100);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nCongrats! It took you " + numGuesses + " guesses to win.");
            numGuesses = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to play again or 2 to quit.");
            keepGoing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            while (keepGoing != 1 && keepGoing != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease type either 1 or 2 only!");
                keepGoing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (keepGoing == 2)
            {
                playAgain = false;
                say.Goodbye();
            }

            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                difficulty.SetDifficulty();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise runningBalance to initialBalance and only use this value for calculations. If you only need initialBalance once, you can also do it by simply switching runningBalance to initialBalance without initializing runningBalance.

```
 Console.WriteLine("\nBeggining credit balance = " + initialBalance);
 Console.WriteLine("\nPlease place a bet. You will lose those credits for every incorrect guess!");
 bet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 runningBalance = initialBalance
 do
 {
     Console.WriteLine("\nGuess a number between 1 and 100.");
     userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     numGuesses++;

     UI output = new UI();
     output.CompareNumbers(userGuess, ref selectedNumber, ref playAgain, ref numGuesses);


     runningCredits -= bet;
     Console.WriteLine("\nYou have " + runningCredits + " credits remaining.");

 } while (playAgain == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
runningCredits = (initialBalance - bet);
```

You don't change `initialBalance` or `bet` in the loop, so every iteration has the same value of `runningCredits`.

Outside the loop, do this:

```
runningCredits = initialBalance;
```

Inside the loop, do this:

```
runningCredits -= bet;
```

**Note:** you don't have any code to check in the loop to see if the user guessed right or wrong (and as such, the user always loses and you always subtract out the bet).

Comment: I originally had it changed but again, it kepis resetting to what it was originally declared as anyway so it wasn't work.

Comment: The methods for comparing the answer is called in an if statement in the other class... Also, what does the -= do? Sorry, quite new to this if you couldn't already tell. Thanks for the help as well @crashmstr

Comment: `runniningCredits -= bet;` is the same as `runningCredits = runningCredits - bet;`. As far as the answer test, you need it at this level, so return a bool or add another reference parameter (prefer a return value) so that you know if they won or lost and if you add or remove from the `runningCredits`.

Comment: @MichaelM that said, you seem to have a strange division where there is user input in your `Control` and game logic in your `UI`.